# RecyclerView: how to refresh data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I refresh internal data in a RecyclerView that is bound to a public static variable?
I've created this Adapter class, and defined all (I think) that I need to create a list of object displayed via a RecyclerView.
Now as you can see in the constructor, there is an internal ArrayList that is built by fetching the data from a public static ArrayList elsewhere.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<StatusBarNotification> myList;
Context ctx;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView appSmallIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        appSmallIcon = // ..
     // ....
    }
}

public void add(int position, StatusBarNotification item) {
    myList.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(StatusBarNotification item) {
    int position = myList.indexOf(item);
    myList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
    if (MyService.allMyData != null)
        myList = new ArrayList<>(MyService.allMyData);
    else
        myList = new ArrayList<>();
    ctx = context;
}

@Override
public MyListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = //... 
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // ....
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myList.size();
}
```

}

After the RecyclerView is created, and the app is running, what should I do to **notify that the external myAllData ArrayList has changed**, or an item added or removed? I tried to invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` but nothing happens. The weird thing (at my eyes, of course) is that I don't have access to methods like add(), remove().

Supposing that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is the correct road to follow, where should I put a listener inside the adapter to actually update the internal data and ask the RecyclerView to refresh the screen? Should I use Intents instead to communicate with my adapter?

And also, why Java prevents me to do something like this:

```
MyListAdapter myLA = new MyListAdapter(....);
myLA.remove(item);    // <-- why the public method remove() is not available?!?
```

I don't understand the syntax and semantics that prevent me from accessing the public methods, as if they were private.

Comment: Can some one explain the reason for the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that my problem was that I supposed that I needed to keep an internal private variable, synchronized with the real external data to be shown. I was wrong: **the Adapter must be directly linked to the data that must be shown, through a reference**. The private copy is just a private reference to the public data, so **copying the addressed data in the constructor is wrong**.
At that point, if the constructor of the Adapter is fed with the reference to some data object, it can be notified at every change with `notifyDataSetChanged()` .

Comment: Hi can you expand on this? I think I'm experiencing a similar problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`notifyDataSetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29), if you encounter rendering problems try `requestLayout` and `forceLayout`.

Comment: Actually notifyDataSetChanged does nothing. It notifies registered observers for data change, but how can I change the data? That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
if (MyService.allMyData != null)
{
   // myList = new ArrayList<>(MyService.allMyData); // This type of initialization don't allow mofification in list. or you can do this 

      myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(MyService.allMyData));
      // or 
      myList = new ArrayList<>();
      myList.addAll(MyService.allMyData);
 }
  else
    myList = new ArrayList<>();
    ctx = context;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not in the constructor. When I invoke notifyDataSetChanged() the constructor is not run again.
Thank you anyway to try to help me with a solution, after 2 days of banging head against docs and tutorials, instead of those that like to downvote a programming question.

Comment: Your welcome. Yes constructor will be called only once.